# JSON file to CSV file conversion using jq

Tags: json, export-to-csv, jq

I am trying to convert my json file to a csv file using jq. Below is the sample input events.json file.

```
{
  "took" : 111,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "alerts",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "alertID" : "639387c3-0fbe-4c2b-9387-c30fbe7c2bc6",
          "alertCategory" : "Server Alert",
          "description" : "Successfully started.",
          "logId" : null
          }
       },
       {
        "_index" : "alerts",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "alertID" : "2",
          "alertCategory" : "Server Alert",
          "description" : "Successfully stoped.",
          "logId" : null
          }
       }
   ]
  }
}
```

My rows in csv should have the data inside each `_source` tag. So my columns would be `alertId` , `alertCategory` , `description` and `logId` with its respective data.

I tried the below command :
`jq --raw-output '.hits[] | [."alertId",."alertCategory",."description",."logId"] | @csv' < /root/events.json`
and its not working.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path-expression is not right, you have a `hits` array inside an object named `hits` and the fields you trying to put in CSV is present under `__source` object.

So your expression should have been below. Use it along with `-r` flag to put the output in raw output format

```
.hits.hits[]._source | [ .alertID, .alertCategory, .description, .logId ] | @csv
```

If your fields are `null`, the string representation of your null field value results in just `""`. If you want an explicit `"null"` string representation, use the alternate operator along with the field you expect to be null, e.g. instead of `.logId`, you can do `(.logId // "null")`

To add the column name as the header in the output CSV format, you could use the `@csv` or the `join(",")` function in raw output format `-r`

```
[ "alertId" , "alertCategory" , "description", "logId" ], 
( .hits.hits[]._source |  [ .alertID, .alertCategory, .description, .logId // "null" ]) | @csv
```

or

```
[ "alertId" , "alertCategory" , "description", "logId" ], 
( .hits.hits[]._source |  [ .alertID, .alertCategory, .description, .logId // "null" ]) | join(",")
```

Comment: A big thanks for your response. I tried this command ```jq -r '.hits.hits[]._source | [."alertId",."alertCategory",."description",."logId" // "null"] | @csv' < /root/events.json```

Two problems : I am not getting the column names as the first row and in some cases, the column ```alertId``` has alphanumeric value like ```639387c3-0fbe-4c2b-9387-c30fbe7c2bc6``` and in those cases, its coming as blank in the output.

Comment: hey it's working now, I used ```alertId``` instead of ```alertID```. Just need help in getting the column names in the first row.

Comment: what if my columns are dynamic inside ```_source``` ?

Comment: @darecoder: Could you ask a separate question for it. With the accepted status, any updates to Q or A in this should be freezed. I'll be glad to answer a new one

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64576887/json-file-to-csv-file-conversion-when-my-json-columns-are-dynamic @Inian