# JSON file to CSV file conversion when my JSON columns are dynamic

Tags: json, shell, csv, export-to-csv, jq

I found the solution for json to csv conversion. Below is the sample json and solution.

```
{
  "took" : 111,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "alerts",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "alertID" : "639387c3-0fbe-4c2b-9387-c30fbe7c2bc6",
          "alertCategory" : "Server Alert",
          "description" : "Successfully started.",
          "logId" : null
          }
       },
       {
        "_index" : "alerts",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "alertID" : "2",
          "alertCategory" : "Server Alert",
          "description" : "Successfully stoped.",
          "logId" : null
          }
       }
   ]
  }
}
```

The solution :

```
jq -r '.hits.hits[]._source | [ "alertID" , "alertCategory" , "description", "logId" ], ([."alertID",."alertCategory",."description",."logId" // "null"]) | @csv' < /root/events.json
```

The problem with this solution is that I have to hard code the column names. What If my json gets a few additions under `_source` tag later? I need a solution which can handle the dynamic data under `_source`. I am open to any other tool or command in shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `keys_unsorted` (or `keys` if you want them sorted). See e.g. [Convert JSON array into CSV using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47730946/convert-json-array-into-csv-using-jq) or [How to convert arbitrary simple JSON to CSV using jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960857/how-to-convert-arbitrary-simple-json-to-csv-using-jq) for two SO examples. There are many others too.